# Adding prefixes to several files in a folder

Tags: vbscript

I found a vbscript that will allow me to update file names to replace "_" with a " " (space) that was very useful. My hope is to make a couple small modifications to this same script to add a prefix to the same files. However, every attempt I have made to do so just gets me stuck in an endless loop that times out and more or less adds an endless amount of prefixes are added. I cannot figure out the correct conditions to exit the loop after one run on each file. Below is the script. Any help is appreciated.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")   
Set Folder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:test")

For Each File In Folder.Files  
    sNewFile = File.Name  
    sNewFile = Replace(sNewFile, "_", "")  
    If (sNewFile <> File.Name) Then  
        File.Move (File.ParentFolder + "\" + sNewFile)  
    End If

Next
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
dim objFSO    : set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
dim objFolder : Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(".")
For Each File In objFolder.Files
    if instr(File.Name, "_") > 0  then
      objFSO.MoveFile File.Name, "PREFIX-" & replace(File.Name, "_", " ") 
    end if
Next
```

For each file in the same directory as the script it will check if the file name has a underscore: If so, then it will rename that file to have a "PREFIX-" string and replace the underscore with a space.

It might be worth commenting out the the MoveFile line and create a new line with:

```
wscript.echo "Renaming: " & File.Name & " to: PREFIX-" & replace(File.Name, "_", " ")
```

E.g.

```
dim objFSO    : set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
dim objFolder : Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(".")
For Each File In objFolder.Files
    if instr(File.Name, "_") > 0  then
      'objFSO.MoveFile File.Name, "PREFIX-" & replace(File.Name, "_", " ") 
      wscript.echo "Renaming: " & File.Name & " to: PREFIX-" & replace(File.Name, "_", " ") 
    end if
Next
```

This will show you what it will do if you run:
cscript script.vbs > out.txt